# Hide a usercontrol present in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpfdatagrid, visibility

I have a usercontrol which I am including in my datagrid column.
But I want to hide that usercontrol on the basis of certain condition.
I tried binding the visibility of that usercontrol but that is not working.I dont know why is that happening.

```
<DataGrid>
... .
... 

  <UserControl:MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding 
SomeProperty,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataGrid>
```

But if I am using the same property in hiding the other controls present in the DataGrid columns.They are working and getting hide on the certain condition.

I dont know what is happening.Please help me guys.

Comment: Is there any binding error in immediate or output window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly set the DataContext property of your UserControl:

```
<UserControl:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding 
SomeProperty,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Otherwise show the full xaml for dataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Since your control is nested in a DataGrid, the DataContext of your databinding is the same as your DataGrid context.

Therefore, you can either choose to bind the visibility of your element to a property of the DataGrid DataContext or bind it to a property of a relative UI parent DataContext or a prox.

I'll take the following model as example.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public class Foo
    {
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public Visibility IsVisible {get;set;}    
    }

    private IList<Foo> _fooList;
    public IList<Foo> FooList {get;set;}

    private Visibility _parentVisibility;
    public Visibility ParentVisibility{get;set}
}
```

Solution 1 (DataGrid datacontext) :

Assuming your datagrid is bound to `FooList` you can straight forward bind to the `IsVisible` property of you `Foo` object as :

```
<UserControl:MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" />
```

Solution 2 (Parent context) :

If you want to bind the visibility of your UserControl to a property that is not in the datagrid context you either have to specify a `RelativeSource` to your binding or a `DataContextProxy`.

Going for the `RelativeSource` solution you can bind the visibility of your UserControl to the `ParentVisibility` property as :

```
<UserControl:MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ParentVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=YourPageUserControl}" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `DataContext.IsVisible` should be correct way to do this. Isn't it?

Comment: @Farzi is it helping for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that there is a binding error coming in Output or Immediate Window.

Why?

Because your control is looking for `SomeProperty` in the collection entity which is not present there.

That property as you suggested is available at the Page ViewModel level.

Therefore do this

```
<UserControl:MyUserControl 
 Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsVisible, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                              AncestorType=YourUserControl}" />
```

Comment: Are you missing `BoolenToVisibilityConverter` if property is of bool type.?

Comment: Put a Breakpoint on Property Setter and Getter to see if it comes there. First it should come on set and then get.

Comment: BindingExpression path error: 'InventoryVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel' (HashCode=66609888)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.InventoryVisibility; DataItem='MyUserControl' (Name=''); target element is 'MyUserControl' (Name='MultiUnitCombo'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')